# How to enable Socket in PHP 5.3.10 on Ubuntu 12.04 System

Tags: php, php-socket

I am trying to enable Socket in PHP on linux. I checked php.ini but in that file not getting following line.

```
;extension=php_sockets.so
```

Comment: Which flavour/distribution of linux do you use? How have you deployed php on your machine?

Comment: Also after every change in the ini close and start the server again

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I deployed php using  sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have installed [php5 libapache2-mod-php5](http://packages.debian.org/sid/libapache2-mod-php5), according to it.

> The following extensions are built in: bcmath bz2 calendar Core ctype date dba dom ereg exif fileinfo filter ftp gettext hash iconv json libxml mbstring mhash openssl pcre Phar posix Reflection session shmop SimpleXML soap **sockets** SPL standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tokenizer wddx xml xmlreader xmlwriter zip zlib.

Answer (score 1):

It does not need external module. check phpinfo() result to see if PHP compiled with --enable-sockets or not!  (if you installed it using apt-get or software center of Ubuntu, It must be ok yet!)

Comment: Yes, accorindg to php5_5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2.diff from http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/php/php5 the php core is compiled with `--enable-sockets` -> sockets module should be "within" the php core.